# Vue JS: search filter on numbers

Tags: javascript, vue.js

my below code working good when i search for letters, but when it come for numbers like `flat_number` only it gives me error `flat.flat_number.toLowerCase is not a function`

```js
filteredList() {
  return this.Flats.filter((flat) => {
    return (
      //i tried commented code but it didn;t work
      //  this.Flats.filter(flat_number => String(flat_number).includes(this.search)) ||

      flat.buyer
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
      flat.flat_number //flat_number not working
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
      flat.city
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
    );
  });
},
```

any help please?

Comment: Please share `this.Flats`

Comment: it's an API data @evolutionxbox

Comment: @LucaKiebel i need it for search bar

Comment: well, numbers don't have the `toLowerCase()` method

Comment: @LucaKiebel i tried this but it didn't work `this.Flats.filter(flat_number => String(flat_number).includes(this.search))`

Comment: because `flat_number` in that code is a `flat` (Flats.filter will iterate over the flats), if you use the `String` function on a `flat`, it'll just give you `[object Object]`

Answer (score 2):

There is no `toLowerCase` function for [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#static_methods).

If you want to treat flat as a String type, then do that conversion before comparing to search string.

```js
filteredList() {
    return this.Flats.filter((flat) => {
        return (
            flat.buyer.toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
            flat.flat_number.toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
            flat.city.toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
        );
    });
},
```

Comment: thank you it worked ... i have one more question please, my search bar render very slow do u know why is this?

Comment: It would be difficult to guess without seeing the rest of your project. You might want to create a post with your project at codereview for assistance: 
 https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @sara97 Having said that. the issue may have to due with the volume of data and how you are checking for matching values. `includes` can be expensive because it is scanning the entire string for the search term. You may want to check out how to create a prefix tree, also known as a trie. It's a more efficient way to compare strings: https://learnersbucket.com/tutorials/data-structures/trie-data-structure-in-javascript/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/trie-search

Comment: thank you i will check that